# Navigation Inside TabHost in Android

Tags: android

I have Two tabs inside my main Activity. One is Home Tab And Other is SignIn. My i have created tabs for both of them, But I have another screen for Registration in SignIn Tab. i have a Register button inside SignIn tab, When User Clicks on Register button Registration Activity has to be shown. But Tabbar has to be there on Registration.
HomeTab
SignInTab-->Registration

Comment: I haven't tested this out but I would suggest turning the registration Activity into a Fragment and use [FragmentTabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html). Or, do away with TabHost all together and go for a ViewPager with a tab indicator.

Comment: fragmentTabHost will Support 2.2 version..?

Comment: FragmentTabHost is in the support library, so yes.